# Google cloud resource exhausted, insufficient accelerators

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to run ML training on gcloud, but keep getting this error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.jobs.submit.training) RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Field: scale_tier Error: Insufficient accelerators are available in region US-EAST4 to schedule the job which requests 1 K80 accelerators. Please wait and try again or else try submitting your job to a different region.
    - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
      fieldViolations:
      - description: Insufficient accelerators are available in region US-EAST4 to schedule
          the job which requests 1 K80 accelerators. Please wait and try again or else
          try submitting your job to a different region.
        field: scale_tier
```

After waiting and switching regions/zones, result is the same. Is the traffic really this high everywhere, or i'm doing something wrong? Is there any monitoring/resource available tool, to check for free slots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

US-EAST4 does not have K80 accelerators. Here is a table listing the accelerators and which regions they are available in:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/

I would suggest trying US-EAST1. You might also try US-CENTRAL.

I will use our internal issue tracker to investigate the possibility of improving the error message in this case: there is a difference between requesting an accelerator in a region that doesn't have those vs. a region that has them, but they are all being used.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept this because of the link. Just one more thing, do we have to use the same bucket zone as in gsutil call, or not?

Comment: No. your data can be anywhere. You do, however, want to keep the data as close to possible as your training process to minimize latencies. A multi-regional bucket does try to optimize the placement of the data and should be fairly robust to where you run the job.